# Example for Objects calling each other’s methods recursively

Tags: java, c#, oop, smalltalk, pharo

I’m doing Phd research and in a discussion I mentioned that in OOP, two objects might call each other recursively. My friend then asked me if there is an example of this where this happens in more real world example (not artificial one).

I couldn’t come up with one.

Pseudocode for an artificial example without showing constructors:

```
class A
  private B b;
  void a1() {  b.b1(); }
  void a2() { print “finished”; }

class B
  private A a;
  void b1() { a.a2(); }
```

Method linearisation is:

```
A.a1()  ---->  B.b1()  ----> A.a2()
```

Is there a more real world example where this calling of methods of two different objects might happen?

Comment: I think it would be a bad design ... it should be A.a1()--> B.b1() A.a1()-->A.a2()

Comment: Pardon my comment if it's not spot on, but isn't recursion the call of a method from within itself? In this example you just have sequential calls 
a1() ---> b1() ---> a2() output: finished.

Comment: I removed recursive as it might be misunderstood, better would be mutual calling perhaps.

Comment: Are you saying about double dispatch and visitor pattern?

Comment: Look at some networking examples.  A Token Ring would have object calling each other.  Since there is only one token a conflict wouldn't exist.  A

Comment: @Uko I think visitor pattern is a nice example!

Comment: @IoannisStefanou there's recursion and there's mutual recursion. Two (or three or n) methods calling each other are mutually recursive. In this case they're different methods though.

Comment: @fedes. Well, it felt wrong to use recursion in the description. Intuitively, it feels that mutual recursion belongs more in the area of mathematics. Cool to know the name of this idea though, cheers ;)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at how Smalltalk handles coercion through double dispatch.

In the Squeak image:

```
Float>>+ aNumber
   "Primitive. Answer the sum of the receiver and aNumber. Essential.
    Fail if the argument is not a Float. See Object documentation
    whatIsAPrimitive."

   <primitive: 41>
   ^ aNumber adaptToFloat: self andSend: #+

Integer>>adaptToFloat: rcvr andSend: selector 
   "If I am involved in arithmetic with a Float, convert me to a Float."
   ^ rcvr perform: selector with: self asFloat
```

So if you do `1.5 + 3`, you send `+` to 1.5 (a Float), 1.5 sends `adaptToFloat:andSend:` to 3 (an Integer), and 3 sends `+` to the 1.5 again (second time with `3 asFloat` instead of `3`).

Wouldn't call it recursion with just two steps, but it's close to your example.

NOTE: The primitive in `Float>>+` fails, and the Smalltalk code after it gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You agreed with @Sanjeev that it should not happen at all in real example, because it is wrong on so many levels but let's assume a lousy designer did that mistake; it could be done in a lot of cases. for example: a Bank system where the balance calculation function is done in the account object, but because the customer might have more that one account (and the account can be owned by many customers). the designer thought that it would be a good idea to be able to calculate the customers balance across all accounts from any of the accounts objects, and that it should be done through the relation with the cutomer. using your code example:

```
class BankAccount
  private Customer cust;
  void TotalBalance() {  cust.Balance(); }
  void OwnersBalance() { print “finished”; }

class Customer
  private Account acc;
  void Balance() { acc.OwnersBalance(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In hope that I correctly understood what you need, this is a possible real life example.

Imagine the case that a manager receives a project that needs to be delivered.
The manager hands the project to the employee, and  the employee finishes the project that gets delivered to the client.

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emploeyee = new Employee();
        ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager(emploeyee);

        projectManager.initiateProject();
    }

    public static class ProjectManager {
        Employee emploeyee;

        public ProjectManager(Employee emploeyee) {
            this.emploeyee = emploeyee;
        }

        public void initiateProject() {
            System.out.println("Manager Starts project...");
            this.emploeyee.finishProject(this);
        }

        public void deliverProjectToClient() {
            System.out.println("Manager delivers finished project to client");
        }
    }

    public static class Employee {

        public Employee() {

        }

        public void finishProject(ProjectManager projectManager) {
            System.out.println("Employee delivers finished project to manager");
            projectManager.deliverProjectToClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Manager Starts project... 
Employee delivers finished project to manager
Manager delivers finished project to client
```

Hope this helps